# Prove that if every smooth function on a subset of a manifold can be extended to a smooth function on the whole manifold, then the subset is closed.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Consider a nonempty subset $A$ of a smooth manifold $M$ and suppose that every smooth function on $A$ can be extended to a smooth function on $M$. We want to show that $A$ is closed. How might we proceed with a proof?

Since $M$ is a manifold, $A$ is Hausdorff. Thus if $A$ is closed if it is compact. To construct a finite cover of $A$ by open sets, let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^k$ be a smooth function on $A$ so $f$ extends to a smooth function $F:M\to\mathbb{R}^k$ on $M$. Consider an arbitrary cover $C=\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in X\}$ of $A$. We must show that $C$ has a finite subcover.

I am not sure now how to proceed. I would like to think there is a way to use the fact that for all open sets $B\subseteq M$ such that $A\cap B$ is nonempty, we can let $F|_B$ be the restriction of $F$ to $B$ and get a finite cover of $A$ by pulling back the image of the intersection. (This isn't sufficient, it's just a sense that we should look at images in $\mathbb{R}^k$.)

What are some ideas that I can use to get started?

Comment: "$A$ is closed iff it is compact" how do you conclude this? This is completely false in general. Moreover, your proof shows nothing: $\{M\}$ is a finite open cover of any of its subsets. To prove that $A$ is compact, you need to _start_ with an arbitrary open cover of it and show that it has a finite subcover.

Comment: How do you define smooth functions on arbitrary subsets of manifolds? The claim you are trying to prove most likely says "closed" instead of "compact." Where did this problem come from?

Comment: I thought that the implication "If a subspace of a Hausdorff space is compact, then it is closed" was true.

Comment: The converse of that implication is not true: $[0, \infty)$ is closed in the Hausdorff space $\Bbb{R}$, but it is not compact.

Comment: Oops...thank you. Extra "f" has been deleted.

Comment: Here is one definition of smoothness that topologists like to use: Suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold, $A\subset M$ is a subset. A function $f$ defined on $A$ is called smooth if for every $a\in A$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ in $M$ such that $f|(A\cap U)$ extends to a smooth function on $U$.

Comment: Which definition of smooth do you use if $A$ is not open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in the title of this question is wrong. Consider $A=M=\mathbb{R}$. Then, clearly any smooth function on $A$ can be extended to one on $M$. But $A$ is not compact.

Of course, $A$ is still closed. Hence, this example does not disprove the statement from your post. It does, however, show that your approach (showing closedess by showing compactness) cannot succeed.

---

With regards to the statement in the body of the question: I would suggest trying to show closedness of $A$ more directly. Or, equivalently, openness of $M\setminus A$: I.e. take any point $x \in M\setminus A$ and try to show that there exists an open neighborhood of $x$ which does not intersect $A$.

To start you might just use an open neighborhood you get from $M$ being a manifold. This neighborhood might, of course, intersect $A$. But we also haven't used the assumption that we can extend smooth functions on $A$ yet. So we have to find some smooth function such that it's extendability says something interesting.

Maybe some function that we know cannot be extended at $x$? Then, the fact that its restriction to $A$ can be extended to the whole of $M$ (including $x$) might say something about how "close" $A$ and $x$ can get.

---

As a meta-hint (assuming that this is an exercise from a text book or lecture): Since compactness is a stronger property than closedness (in a Hausdorff space) it is unlikely that your type of approach would be the intended one even if one does not know the above counter example (as, then, the exercise would most likely have been stated as "Show that $A$ is compact.")

Of course, this doesn't guarantee that the approach cannot work. But one should at least be skeptical about whether it can be the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. I learned a lot from your answer. What does it mean to say a function cannot be extended at a point? My instinct is to say something like, "$f$ can be extended at $x$ if $x$ is in the domain at $f$ and $f$ can be extended to a nbhd of $x$ that is not already contained in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Do you know any functions on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ that cannot be extended to $\mathbb{R}$? Can you extend this idea to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$? To $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$?
If so, you are essentially done since manifolds locally look like $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Is this consistent with what you are suggesting?

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a smooth atlas on $M$ such that a chart $(V,\phi)$, $\phi:V\to\hat{V}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ for which $x\in V$ is taken to $0$, and define a (smooth) function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$. Then $f\circ\psi:M\to\mathbb{R}$ cannot be extended at $x$.

Comment: Or is your suggestion to show that if $A$ is open (or open and closed), then not every smooth function on $A$ can be extended to a smooth function on $M$?

Comment: I'm trying to come to grips with why there can be a function that cannot be extended at $x$, even though its restriction to a closed subset can be extended to $x$. What would this look like? Perhaps part of the problem is that I don't know how this relates to there being an open neighborhood about $x$ disjoint from $A$.

Comment: The function you suggest is exactly the one I had in mind. Maybe it helps to first only think of the case $M=\mathbb{R}^n$. And, to make it really easy, assume $0 \notin A$ and you just want to prove that there is an open neighbourhood of $0$ which does not intersect $A$. There, you can directly apply $\phi$ (use a proof by contradiction).

Btw. the approach you propose in your second comment does not work as a set can be neither closed nor open (i.e $(0,1]$)